# Write query with HAVING clause in Kotlin with Exposed

Tags: sql, database, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have written an SQL query in which I use the HAVING clause.

However, I have not found practical examples of the use of HAVING in the Exhibited documentation.

My query should return the following:

- Disputes for an order that has the most recent status of 'CAPTURED' or 'EXPIRED'

```
SELECT pc.*
FROM "pedido" p
INNER JOIN pedido_contestacao pc ON t.id = pc.pedido_id
WHERE p.number = '1234'
GROUP BY pc.id
HAVING (
   SELECT status
   FROM contestacao_event ce
   WHERE ce.pedido_contestacao_id = pc.id
   ORDER BY ce.created_at DESC
   limit 1
   ) IN ('CAPTURED', 'EXPIRED')
```

My biggest difficulty is writing the HAVING sub query. I saw that there is a function called wrapAsExpression, but I can't use it in this scenario. My query so far looks like this:

```
val contestacaoEventTable = ContestacaoEventTable.alias("det")
val pedidoContestacaoTable = PedidoContestacaoTable.alias("tdt")

val subQuery = contestacaoEventTable
    .slice(contestacaoEventTable[ContestacaoEventTable.status])
    .selectAll()
    .andWhere {​​​​​​​​
        ContestacaoEventTable.id eq pedidoContestacaoTable[PedidoContestacaoTable.id]
    }​​​​​​​​.orderBy(ContestacaoEventTable.createdAt to SortOrder.DESC)
    .limit(1)
    .alias("statusQuery")

val status = contestacaoEventTable[ContestacaoEventTable.status]
PedidoTable
    .innerJoin(PedidoContestacaoTable)
    .slice(PedidoContestacaoTable.columns)
    .selectAll()
    .groupBy(PedidoContestacaoTable.id)
    .andWhere {​​​​​​​​ PedidoTable.number eq '1234' }​​​​​​​​
.having {​​​​​​​​
        // wrapAsExpression(subQuery.slice(status).selectAll()).inList(listOf("CAPTURED", "EXPIRED"))
}​​​​​​​​.map {​​​​​​​​
    println(it[PedidoContestacaoTable.id])
}​​​​​​​​
```

I don't know what else to do to make it work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sorry for the delay! You are the man! Saved my development!

I made some adaptations to your suggestion.

My solution was as follows:

```
fun <T : Any> wrapAsExpressionWithColumnType(query: Query, columnType: IColumnType) =
    object : ExpressionWithColumnType<T?>() {
        private val expression = wrapAsExpression<T>(query)
        override fun toSQL(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) = expression.toSQL(queryBuilder)
        override val columnType: IColumnType = columnType
    }
```

And the final code for the query:

```
transaction {
    val contestacaoEventTable = ContestacaoEventTable.alias("det")
    val pedidoContestacaoTable = PedidoContestacaoTable.alias("tdt")

    val contestacaoEventTransacaoId = contestacaoEventTable[ContestacaoEventTable.contestacaoTransacaoId]
    val contestacaoEventCreatedAt = contestacaoEventTable[ContestacaoEventTable.createdAt]
    val contestacaoEventStatus = contestacaoEventTable[ContestacaoEventTable.status]

    val pedidoContestacaoId = pedidoContestacaoTable[PedidoContestacaoTable.id]
    val pedidoContestacaoTransacaoId = pedidoContestacaoTable[PedidoContestacaoTable.transacaoId]

    val subQuery = contestacaoEventTable
        .slice(contestacaoEventTable[ContestacaoEventTable.status])
        .selectAll()
        .andWhere { contestacaoEventTransacaoId eq pedidoContestacaoId }
        .orderBy(contestacaoEventCreatedAt to SortOrder.DESC)
        .limit(1)
        .alias("subQuery")
    PedidoTable
        .innerJoin(pedidoContestacaoTable, { PedidoTable.id }, { pedidoContestacaoTransacaoId })
        .slice(pedidoContestacaoId)
        .selectAll()
        .groupBy(pedidoContestacaoId)
        .andWhere { PedidoTable.number eq '1234' }
        .having {
            wrapAsExpressionWithColumnType<String>(subQuery.query, contestacaoEventStatus.columnType)
                .inList(listOf(PedidoStatus.CAPTURED.name, PedidoStatus.EXPIRED.name))
        }.toList().size
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help . Hope I can help other people.

Comment: So you used the same code as another answer, posted that as an answer and accepted your own? Why? If someone helped you solve your problem you should accept their answer

Answer (score 4):

`inList` method is defined only for the `ExpressionWithColumnType` class, not for any `Expression`, so you need to write auxiliary function to wrap sub-query into `ExpressionWithColumnType`:

```kotlin
fun <T : Any> wrapAsExpressionWithColumnType(query: AbstractQuery<*>, columnType: IColumnType) =
    object : ExpressionWithColumnType<T?>() {
        private val expression = wrapAsExpression<T>(query)

        override fun toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) = expression.toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder)
        override val columnType: IColumnType = columnType
    }
```

so your `having` subclause will be:

```kotlin
.having {
    wrapAsExpressionWithColumnType<String>(subQuery.query, status.columnType) inList listOf("CAPTURED", "EXPIRED")
}
```

Also note, that when you use table alias, you should refer (in `slice`, `andWhere`, `orderBy`, and other clauses) to columns of the alias, not of the original table.

So, if you use alias in a sub-query, the main query should use alias too (or vice versa)